# UPDATE query, LIMIT and RETURNING order

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax, updates

I am working on a LIVE database and due to the current circumstances, cannot test the query without putting it live... bad i know...

Basically its a simple update but I only want it to update the latest matched row:

```
UPDATE person SET name = 'bob' WHERE cousin = 'jane' ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1 RETURNING id
```

Basically, many "people" can have jane as a cousin, I only want to set the name of the most recent person to bob. I am just not sure about the LIMIT and RETURNING clauses. Are they in the right order? or can you even use LIMIT and RETURNING together?

Comment: Please define "the most recent person"

Comment: Even if you need to test in production, you can wrap your experiments in `BEGIN` ... `ROLLBACK`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE person
SET name = 'bob'
WHERE id = (
    select max(id)
    from person
    where cousin = 'jane'
    )
RETURNING id;
```

You can test it by first starting a transaction:

```
begin;

UPDATE person
SET name = 'bob'
WHERE id = (
    select max(id)
    from person
    where cousin = 'jane'
    )
RETURNING id;
```

Now select the result:

```
select *
from person
where id = id_returned_in_the_above_query;
```

If it is correct then commit:

```
commit;
```

Else rollback:

```
rollback;
```